# stop words in sitecore

Tags: lucene, sitecore

We are using Lucene for text search as part of sitecore.
Is there any method to ignore stop words (like a,an,the...) in the sitecore search?

Comment: What's a use case of this? If you search **the cat in the hat** you want it to really just search as if you entered **cat hat**? Or do you mean filter them out in the results?

Answer (score 14):

By default, Sitecore uses Lucene standard analyzer - `Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer`. You can see this is defined in `/configuration/sitecore/search/analyzer` element of web.config file. One of the constructors of `StandardAnalyzer` class accepts the array of strings it will consider stop words. By default it uses the hardcoded list of stop words which include:

> "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at",
>   "be", "but", "by", "for", "if", "in",
>   "into", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of",
>   "on", "or", "such", "that", "the",
>   "their", "then", "there", "these",
>   "they", "this", "to", "was", "will",
>   "with"

If you'd like to override this behavior, I think you should inherit `StandardAnalyzer` and override its default constructor to take the stop words from another source instead of the hardcoded array.  You have various options, even reading it from a text file. Don't forget to replace the standard class with yours in web.config.

See other constructors of `StandardAnalyzer` class for more details. [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is your friend here.

Comment: What do you mean? The code I reference in the answer above is placed in Lucene.Net.dll (in Sitecore /bin folder). You can browse this third-party library with .NET Reflector. What I propose to do in your case is to create a new class, inherit it from StandardAnalyzer, and make the default constructor search the stop words in another way (the way you choose). There are examples of this in the code of other constructors of StandardAnalyzer class.

Comment: BTW, Alex Shyba has just published an amazing summary blog post about searching with Sitecore & Lucene: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/02/8-reasons-to-use-new-search-in-sitecore.html. This post is also full of useful links to various resources about the topic. Be sure to check it out before moving forward in this area!

Answer (score 4):

An example for Yans post:

```
public class CaseAnalyzer : Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer
{
   private static Hashtable stopWords = new Hashtable(); //{{"by","by"}}; <-- Makes "by" a stopword that will not be matched in analyzer
   public CaseAnalyzer() : base(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, stopWords)
   {      
   }
}
```

this should be registered in the web.config under

```
/configuration/sitecore/search/analyzer
```

an example of the analyzer registration

```
<caseanalyzer type="EBF.Business.Search.Analyzers.CaseAnalyzer, EBF.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
```

Lastly you just need to register your analyzer in the search configuration like this

```
<Analyzer ref="search/caseanalyzer" />
```