# prepositions are ignored by the Lucene index

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a sitecore Lucene index, when i search for prepositions like "of, the ..." it return nothing, but when i remove this words i get the correct result

the following is my search

```cs
 var innerPredict = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
 foreach (string key in keyword.Split(new char[0]))
 {
       innerPredict = innerPredict.And(i => i.Content.Contains(key));
 }

 var query = index.CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(innerPredict);
```

Ex :-
search for "holding of equity"  return null, but search for "holding equity" without the "of" return the correct data.

How can i index the prepositions ?  what configuration control this

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871709/stop-words-in-sitecore

Comment: Dont add a screenshot of your code! Add the actual code with the correct markup.

Comment: These are ignored on purpose as they would be present on virtually all documents. You might want to strip them from your keyword before constructing your predicate. The standard analyzer's stop words (from Yan's answer within the thread Marek pointed to) are exposed (Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS) so you could check if that collection contains your key